# MySql server configuration for maximum 60000 rows with excel file

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query which is fetching 60000 rows and creating excel file which should be available for download as excel file, but every time I am getting some errors like '500 internal server error' or 'mysql server has gone away'. But it works fine for lesser rows(10-15k) Here is mysql query:

```
SELECT C.*, T.Name AS TankName, T.*, P.*
FROM properties P
LEFT JOIN contacts C ON C.ID = P.ContactID AND C.CompanyID = $companyID
LEFT JOIN tanks T on T.PropertyID = P.ID $subQuery
WHERE P.CompanyID = $companyID
    $condition
ORDER BY C.FullName = '', C.LastName, P.City, P.Address, P.ID
```

Do I need to optimize the query or change some sql configuration.

Comment: why not use batching, like get 500 rows write it to excel, get more append to excel and so on...

Comment: As per your comment I tried batching but it didn't work after 30000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your my.cnf variables...
If this is innodb table or myisam table, according to this increase variables value in my.cnf.

Either memory is used up and server terminates the query or restarts mysql...

what error log give in this query ?

Thanks

Comment: I increased almost all of the variables in my.cnf but still its giving me a blank page. and nothing is there in error logs. :(

Comment: First try to execute the query directly on database interface through command line interface or GUI tool.
So that you exactly know is there any problem to mysql end or at application packet level.

Thanks

Comment: Query is fetching 60000 rows but when we are inserting all those data into phpexcel cell its consuming lot of memory. I think that is causing the problem.